# "Taxes are" in my sentence

Tags: word-choice

Should it be "taxes are" not "is"?  The subject is "taxes" and it's plural but  I am confused by "a system".

"Taxes are a system of checks and balances."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Taxes are a system" might seem strange but it sounds perfectly normal to me. No one would call you out if they heard you say this sentence aloud.

It may be more correct to say "*Taxation* is a system;" this avoids the count mismatch and makes more sense from a syntax and logic standpoint. You can make the argument both ways for "taxes" being a system in their own right or just the manifestation of that system, but "taxation" is undoubtedly a system.

Comment: I agree that Taxation is the better word when talking about a system. **Taxes** is used much more in American English than in British English: we Brits usually regard **tax** as uncountable, and so we don't use the plural much.